# How to fetch all ip addresses that are pinged my application on Application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

So, I'm new on Azure and I'm struggling with one problem.
I would like to fetch all IP addresses that pinged my application(Application gateway).
I'm trying with log analytics but I can not find some kinda example which is doing something like that. The thing that I want is to fetch a list with the most requests in the past 1 hours or something like that, but just to fetch the IP addresses will be a great start. I thought this will be an easy task, but I'm really stuck. 
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, logs will be forwarded to Azure monitor. Go there and use a Kusto query to grap the ip addresses:

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(1h) 
| project appName, operation_Name, url, resultCode, client_IP, customDimensions.["client-ip"]
```